# ASP.NET MVC 4 Outputting model data to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My current project involves creating a journal entry for an event.  I am attempting to pull information about the event into the view, however I am not having any success.  How can I get the name and date attributes into the view? (currently there is nothing displayed for these fields in the view).

Models:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
}

public class Journal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string JournalTitle { get; set; }
    public Event JournalEvent { get; set; }
    public string journalEntry { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public UserProfile Patron { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Artist> ArtistsSeen { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model EventJournal3.Models.Journal

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<div class="container">
    <h2>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.JournalTitle)
    </h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.journalEntry)
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.JournalEvent.name)
            <br />
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.JournalEvent.date)
            <br />
            @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.Rating; i++)
            {
                <img src="~/content/star.png" height="25" width="25" />
            }
            <br />
            Artists I've Seen: <br />
            @foreach (var artist in Model.ArtistsSeen)
            {
                @artist.Name <br />
            }
        </div>
        <br />&nbsp;
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-4">
        | @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") |
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Journal journal = db.Journals.Find(id);
        if (journal == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(journal);
    }
```

Comment: Could you make a breakpoint on the return View() to see if threr are valued into the fields? Can you double-check that the Model that you are giving to the view is the same than that one that you refer into the first line of the view?

Comment: Does `db.Journals.Find` actually create an `Event` instance (and populate it) in the returned `Journal` instance?

Comment: @clement Yes, it is the correct model being referred to in the view.

Comment: Are you using an Entity Framework model for your data (I assume yes)? If so, did you use code-first to create the database? If not code-first, are your tables related in the schema?

Comment: @HABO I don't see why it wouldn't.  The ArtistsSeen is properly populated.

Comment: @WTrueBlueAussie Yes I am using code-first Entity Framework.  Yes, my database has all the proper join tables and foreign keys.

Comment: In that case, I am surprised. Unless there is no matching `Event` record for that `Journal` record, then it should exist on the model and display it in the view. If you breakpoint after the `Find()` call, how does the journal object look? Is it missing `JournalEvent`?

Comment: Side note: Just an unrelated suggestion, but also use `Id` fieldnames based on the class/table and not just `Id` on everything. e.g. `EventId` and `JournalId` and tag them with `[Key]`. Trust me when I say it will make maintenance simpler later :)

Comment: @WTrueBlueAussie Ah yes, you were right, it isn't getting the JournalEvent once i looked at it after setting the breakpoint.  The database has the proper foreign keys, but the objects dont seem to be getting populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to make a Viewmodel of your Model what you will show on the view.

```
public class JournalEventViewModel {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string JournalTitle { get; set; }
   public Event JournalEvent { get; set; }
   public string journalEntry { get; set; }
   public int Rating { get; set; }
   public UserProfile Patron { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string location { get; set; }
   public string date { get; set; }
}
```

And cross this to your view. It will behave like an object, so fill this one up with the data from your objects. You can use AutoMapper or map the Viewmodel itself.

Comment: Or just an .Include("Event") in your dbquery